Turning arbitrary structs into hierarchy nodes
The following example is basic node hierarchy implementation which I would like to embed into other structs:
package main

import "fmt"

type NodeInterface interface {
    AddChild(child NodeInterface)
    RemoveChild(child NodeInterface)
    RemoveFromParent()
    setParent(parent NodeInterface)
}

type Node struct {
    parent  NodeInterface
    children []NodeInterface
}

func (n *Node) setParent(parent NodeInterface) {
    n.parent = parent
}

func (n *Node) AddChild(child NodeInterface) {
    n.children = append(n.children, child)
    child.setParent(n)
}

func (n *Node) RemoveChild(child NodeInterface) {
    found := false
    var index int
    for i, node := range n.children {
        if node == child {
            found = true
            index = i
            break
        }
    }
    if found {
        n.children = append(n.children[:index], n.children[index+1:]...)
    } else {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("child not found; given: %T; existing: %T", child, n.children[0]))
    }
}

func (n *Node) RemoveFromParent() {
    n.parent.RemoveChild(n)
}

func main() {
    apex := &Node{}
    cl := &Node{}
    apex.AddChild(cl)
    cl.RemoveFromParent()
}

So, when I try this:
type Foo struct {
    Node
}

func main() {
    apex := &Foo{}
    cl := &Foo{}
    apex.AddChild(cl)
    cl.RemoveFromParent()
}

it panics:
child not found; given: *main.Node; existing: *main.Foo

— which is kind-of understandable.
But how to get it to work? I do want to bring the ability to form hierarchies to arbitrary structs like Foo.

It's usually more natural to use generics for containers — here Node[T] can be a node that has data T. You don't need an interface, and you don't have the problem that the node methods return an interface type rather than the actual type they contain.

Your code has the problem that you're assuming inheritance, a *Node is never a subclass of Node (like in languages that have inheritance), it's always a pointer to a Node, so if you call the method on a type that embeds Node, it'll be a pointer to the Node in the embedded type (and from there it's difficult (and obscure when possible) to get back to the embedding type).

@PaulHankin okay, so how to rewrite this example with generics or whatever?

For example https://go.dev/play/p/83r3fH-uwnj

@PaulHankin Your approach is to move away from embedding to wrapping. It works without generics.

The problem lies in the difference of the entities being compared in this line:
if node == child {

One is Node, the other is whatever type embeds Node (Foo in this case).
So, if we make both Node, that will be it. But how?
Implement getNode():
func (n *Node) getNode() NodeInterface {
    return n
}

and then compare Nodes:
if node.getNode() == child.getNode() {

Full example.

If you would like generic data structures, using generics would be a better approach. There are already multiple implementations available, so I won't repeat that here.
The interesting question might be why the “kind-of understandable” case fails.
Lets look at a simple method declaration first:
func (receiver *Node) Method(parameter NodeInterface) {
    ni := NodeInterface(receiver)
    _, rok := ni.(*Foo)
    _, pok := parameter.(*Foo)

    fmt.Printf("I'm a %T (castable to *Foo: %v) called with a %T (castable to *Foo: %v)\n", ni, rok, parameter, pok)
}

func main() {
    apex := &Foo{}
    apex.Method(apex)
}

type NodeInterface interface {
    Method(NodeInterface)
}

type Node struct{}

type Foo struct {
    Node
}

This gives “I'm a *main.Node (castable to *Foo: false) called with a *main.Foo (castable to *Foo: true)”, try it on the Go Playground.
Okay, we knew that - apex.Method(apex) is syntactic sugar for (&(*apex).Node).Method(apex).
You can't downcast the receiver even when it's embedded, that information is lost by taking a pointer to the inner structure.
Interfaces on the other hand keep the original type.
What would work would be
func main() {
    apex := &Foo{}
    cl := &Foo{}
    apex.AddChild(&cl.Node)
    cl.RemoveFromParent()
}

which is syntactic sugar for
func main() {
    apex := &Foo{}
    cl := &Foo{}
    (&(*apex).Node).AddChild(&(*cl).Node)
    (&(*cl).Node).RemoveFromParent()
}

And here you add and remove NodeInterface(&(*cl).Node) (or NodeInterface(&cl.Node) if you like), which works.
On the other hand NodeInterface(cl) is a different value and not equal.
Try for example
func (Foo) RemoveFromParent() {
    fmt.Println("I would prefer rather not to")
}

func main() {
    apex := &Foo{}
    cl := &Foo{}
    apex.AddChild(cl)
    cl.RemoveFromParent()
}

which does not call cl.Node.RemoveFromParent at all.

Edit
Genericized your code looks like this (Go Playground):
package main

import "fmt"

type Node[T any] struct {
    Value    T
    parent   *Node[T]
    children []*Node[T]
}

func (n *Node[T]) setParent(parent *Node[T]) {
    n.parent = parent
}

func (n *Node[T]) AddChild(child *Node[T]) {
    n.children = append(n.children, child)
    child.setParent(n)
}

func (n *Node[T]) RemoveChild(child *Node[T]) {
    found := false
    var index int
    for i, node := range n.children {
        if node == child {
            found = true
            index = i

            break
        }
    }
    if found {
        n.children = append(n.children[:index], n.children[index+1:]...)
    } else {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("child not found; given: %T; existing: %T", child, n.children[0]))
    }
}

func (n *Node[T]) RemoveFromParent() {
    n.parent.RemoveChild(n)
}

type Foo struct{}

func main() {
    apex := &Node[*Foo]{Value: &Foo{}}
    cl := &Node[*Foo]{Value: &Foo{}}
    apex.AddChild(cl)
    cl.RemoveFromParent()
}

Generally you expect a tree more to have values at the nodes that the values being nodes themselves.

Thanks for the side insights, but if there is a way to solve the problem in question using generics (or whatever) that would be the answer. The linked b-tree implementations seem way too complex to discern how they solve this specific problem.

@Greendrake I've added a generic version of you code, without interfaces. The somewhat ugly &Node[*Foo]{Value: &Foo{}} could be solved by func NewNode[T any](v T) *Node[T] { return &Node[T]{Value: v} }, then you could write apex := NewNode(&Foo{}); cl := NewNode(&Foo{}).
